# How do hedge funds work?

Tags: mutual-funds, terminology, hedging

I understand the basic idea of hedging - buying contracts on something *today* hoping it will help flatten costs over the long run (eg what Southwest did in the late 90s and early 00s when they bought years worth of oil contracts at exceptionally-low rates).

But how does a hedge fund work? Isn't the basic idea of a mutual fund that it's split across a variety of sources (stocks and/or bonds and/or commodities, etc)?

If so, then how does that differ from the idea of hedging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hedge funds work by investing on variety of instruments including options and derivatives. i.e. they even short sell the stocks if they believe that the market is going down. They may also buy stocks that may not be fundamentally sound, just to make few bucks out of it.

Mutual funds on the other hand stick to purely picking up good stocks that are supposed to give good returns over a period of time. They churn of portfolio is less compared to the Hedge fund.

More details at
http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/173.asp#axzz1uG0sLdmj
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_fund

Comment: Why do you say they "even" short sell stocks? Shorting is common, no?

Comment: Shorting is NOT common for Mutual Funds or Index Funds. Otherwise as a concept it is common.

Comment: No but we are talking about hedge funds here, isn't it common for hedge funds to short stocks?

Comment: @Pacerier: I think I was trying to answer in context of OP like Hedge Funds even short where as Mutual Funds don't ... but looks like it hasn't come that way in my answer :)